# Notification doesn't reflect the updated example title

Tags: bug, documentation

I've just received a notification for a +1 vote to an example I contributed. One of the contributions I made (that was approved) was to rename the example.

However, the notification was showing the previous title (probably the original one when the example was created).

[image]